# Why does my steam-pressure based Espresso machine not push water through the group head?

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, maintenance

I have A DeLonghi BCO100IU espresso machine, but when I turn it on for espresso, even with a full boiler, no water comes out of the group head. I am certain this machine works on steam pressure, similar to a Moka pot. I have tried descaling with White vinegar and with descaling solution. Still, no water comes out of the group head.

Comment: Does it really have a boiler? I assume this machine has a pump and a heater.

Comment: The instruction manual that I found online refers to a boiler.

Comment: @FrencDavid50 I see. Mostly this kind of machines for end users don't have boilers.